# Rest API working Fine on locally but not on Herkoku

Tags: python, flask, heroku

I tried to host a Flask Server on Heroku. I Worked Fine Locally and give me desired output that is json formatted List of Location in a city.When I hosted It on heroku it had build Successfully But it was not giving me my desired output.

Please Help me And make me understand where i am going wrong

When Working Locally The API gave me this Response

API Call : http://127.0.0.1:5000/get_location_names_Bangalore

```
    {
    "locations": [
    "1st block jayanagar",
    "1st phase jp nagar",
    "2nd phase judicial layout",
    "2nd stage nagarbhavi",
    "5th block hbr layout",
    "5th phase jp nagar",
    "6th phase jp nagar",
    "7th phase jp nagar",
    "8th phase jp nagar",
    "9th phase jp nagar",
    "aecs layout",
    "abbigere",
    "akshaya nagar"
   ]
}
```

After Deploying Server To Heroku
API call : https://xyz##########.herokuapp.com/get_location_names_Bangalore

```
{
"locations": null
}
```

I am working with 2 file named server.py and util.py ....server.py is having necessary routes and util.py is having all neccasary function

server.py

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import util

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/get_location_names_Bangalore', methods=['GET'])
def get_location_names():
    response = jsonify({
        'locations': util.get_location_names()
    })
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    
    return response


@app.route('/predict_home_price_Bangalore', methods=['GET','POST'])
def predict_home_price():
    total_sqft = float(request.form['total_sqft'])
    location = request.form['location']
    bhk = int(request.form['bhk'])
    bath = int(request.form['bath'])

    response = jsonify({
        'estimated_price': util.get_estimated_price(location,total_sqft,bhk,bath)
    })
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')

    return response

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Starting Python Flask Server For Home Price Prediction...")
    util.load_saved_artifacts()
    app.run()
```

util.py

```
import json
import pickle
import numpy as np

__location = None
__data_columns = None
__model = None


def get_estimated_price(location,sqft,bhk,bath):
    try:
        loc_index = __data_columns.index(location.lower())
    except:
        loc_index = -1

    x = np.zeros(len(__data_columns))
    x[0] = sqft
    x[1] = bath
    x[2] = bhk
    if loc_index >= 0:
        x[loc_index] = 1

    return round(__model.predict([x])[0],2)

def get_location_names():
    return __location

def load_saved_artifacts():
    print("Loading saved artifacts")
    global __location
    global __data_columns

    with open("bangalore_columns.json",'r') as f:
        __data_columns = json.load(f)['data_columns']
        __location = __data_columns[3:]


    global __model
    with open("banglore_home_prices_model.pickle",'rb') as f:
        __model = pickle._load(f)

        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    load_saved_artifacts()
    #print(get_location_names())
    #print(get_estimated_price('1st phase jp nagar',1000,3,3))
```

Requirement.txt

```
Flask==1.1.2
gunicorn==20.0.4
numpy==1.18.1
```

Procfile

```
web: gunicorn server:app
```

Comment: Did you check whether your Heroku environment loads the JSON file's data?

Comment: No i have not checked that  . Can you help me with that ? I do not know how to interact with heroku environment for checking whether it is loading JSON file's data or not

Comment: I think it is better to add some print lines inside the `with open("bangalore_columns.json",'r') as f:` block and see. You can print the data_columns variable and check there.

Comment: i added a `print(__data_columns)`  statement after `__data_columns = json.load(f)['data_columns']` and run the the script the in heroku environment it print all data colums correctly but it also gave an error stating 

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'` 

Shall i add sklearn module in requirement.txt ?

Comment: Yes. Add it and re-deploy

Comment: I added it and redeployed managed to remove the error but the result is same aka `{
"locations": null
}`

Comment: Call the function : `load_saved_artifacts()` outside the main condition block

Comment: Thanks @Harshana Serasinghe this solved my problem ! i called `load_saved_artifacts()` outside the loop aka under `app = Flask(__name__)`  . Thanks a lot! 

But i still wonder why it was is not working when working in loop

Comment: I added a detailed answer. You can check :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have added the main condition for both files. In Python, You can name only one file as "**main**" and it should be the entry point of the application. In your case, the server.py file is the main file.

In your util.py file, Call the function: `load_saved_artifacts()` outside the loop. It will solve the issue.

```
import json
import pickle
import numpy as np

__location = None
__data_columns = None
__model = None


def get_estimated_price(location,sqft,bhk,bath):
    try:
        loc_index = __data_columns.index(location.lower())
    except:
        loc_index = -1

    x = np.zeros(len(__data_columns))
    x[0] = sqft
    x[1] = bath
    x[2] = bhk
    if loc_index >= 0:
        x[loc_index] = 1

    return round(__model.predict([x])[0],2)

def get_location_names():
    return __location

def load_saved_artifacts():
    print("Loading saved artifacts")
    global __location
    global __data_columns

    with open("bangalore_columns.json",'r') as f:
        __data_columns = json.load(f)['data_columns']
        __location = __data_columns[3:]


    global __model
    with open("banglore_home_prices_model.pickle",'rb') as f:
        __model = pickle._load(f)

        

load_saved_artifacts()
```